# Tensorflow error: Input signature not matching inputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, data-science-model

I've been following Sentdex's tutorials on YouTube about Deep Learning and I've encountered and error while trying to load an image and run it through the model. The error says that the inputs do not match the input signature but I've been struggling to find out how to change that.
Any help would be really appreciated! 
The code for loading the model and test image is below:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 50
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("PyCharmProject\\64x3-CNN.model")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('PyCharmProject\dog.jpg')])
print(prediction)
```

and the error I am receiving:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-241c64aef27c> in <module>
     12 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("PyCharmProject\\64x3-CNN.model")
     13 
---> 14 prediction = model.predict([prepare('PyCharmProject\dog.jpg')])
     15 print(prediction)

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    912         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    913         workers=workers,
--> 914         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    915 
    916   def reset_metrics(self):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, **kwargs)
    444     return self._model_iteration(
    445         model, ModeKeys.PREDICT, x=x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose,
--> 446         steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
    447 
    448 

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _model_iteration(self, model, mode, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps, callbacks, **kwargs)
    426               mode=mode,
    427               training_context=training_context,
--> 428               total_epochs=1)
    429           cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, result, mode)
    430 

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    120         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    121       try:
--> 122         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    123       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    124         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     82     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     83     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 84                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     85 
     86   return execution_function

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    447     # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    448     initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 449     self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    450     if self._created_variables:
    451       try:

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    390     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    391         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 392             *args, **kwds))
    393 
    394     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1837     if self.input_signature:
   1838       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1839     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1840     return graph_function
   1841 

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2137         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2138         if graph_function is None:
-> 2139           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2140           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2141         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2028             arg_names=arg_names,
   2029             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2030             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2031         self._function_attributes,
   2032         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    333         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    334         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 335         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    336     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    337 

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     69     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
     70     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 71         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
     72     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     73     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    762       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    763                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 764       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    765 
    766   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1803       kwargs = {}
   1804     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1805       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1806 
   1807   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2148         self._container_strategy(),
   2149         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2150       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2151 
   2152   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in _predict_on_batch(***failed resolving arguments***)
    158     def _predict_on_batch(model, x, y=None, sample_weights=None):
    159       del y, sample_weights
--> 160       return predict_on_batch(model, x)
    161 
    162     func = _predict_on_batch

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in predict_on_batch(model, x)
    366 
    367   with backend.eager_learning_phase_scope(0):
--> 368     return model(inputs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    848                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    849                 else:
--> 850                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    851 
    852             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    253       if not self.built:
    254         self._init_graph_network(self.inputs, self.outputs, name=self.name)
--> 255       return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    256 
    257     outputs = inputs  # handle the corner case where self.layers is empty

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    695                                 ' implement a `call` method.')
    696 
--> 697     return self._run_internal_graph(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    698 
    699   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
    840 
    841           # Compute outputs.
--> 842           output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
    843 
    844           # Update tensor_dict.

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    848                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    849                 else:
--> 850                   outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    851 
    852             except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\utils.py in return_outputs_and_add_losses(*args, **kwargs)
     55     inputs = args[inputs_arg_index]
     56     args = args[inputs_arg_index + 1:]
---> 57     outputs, losses = fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
     58     layer.add_loss(losses, inputs)
     59     return outputs

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    439       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    440       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 441       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    442       if self._created_variables:
    443         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1811   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1812     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
-> 1813     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1814     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1815 

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2094     if self.input_signature is None or args is not None or kwargs is not None:
   2095       args, kwargs = self._function_spec.canonicalize_function_inputs(
-> 2096           *args, **kwargs)
   2097 
   2098     cache_key = self._cache_key(args, kwargs)

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in canonicalize_function_inputs(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1640           inputs,
   1641           self._input_signature,
-> 1642           self._flat_input_signature)
   1643       return inputs, {}
   1644 

~\LT1Kqob5UDEML61gCyjnAcfMXgkdP3wGcge-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _convert_inputs_to_signature(inputs, input_signature, flat_input_signature)
   1706       flatten_inputs)):
   1707     raise ValueError("Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:\n%s" %
-> 1708                      format_error_message(inputs, input_signature))
   1709 
   1710   if need_packing:

ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
  inputs: (
    Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 50, 50, 1), dtype=uint8))
  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

​
​
I assume it might be of relevance I'll put the code for building the model below too:

````
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pickle
import time

X = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb")))
y = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb")))

X = X/255.0

dense_layers = [1]
layer_sizes = [64]
conv_layers = [3]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            NAME = "{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs\{}'.format(NAME))
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
            model.add(Activation("relu"))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

            for l in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3)))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

            model.add(Flatten())

            for l in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation("relu"))

            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

            model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
                         optimizer = "adam",
                         metrics = ['accuracy'])

            model.fit(X, y, batch_size=13, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, steps_per_epoch=1727, callbacks=[tensorboard])

model.save('64x3-CNN.model')
```
````

Comment: Can you try `model.predict(prepare('PyCharmProject\dog.jpg'))`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried before and with some hope I just tried again but I just returns the same error.

Comment: Could you reshape your input to `X.shape[1:]` in your model?

Comment: But that is the way it is, you can see the way I've build my model in the lowest code box.
My first layer is this: model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))

Comment: I meant the output shape of `prepare('PyCharmProject\dog.jpg')` should match the shape of `X.shape[1:]` in your model. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but I am not sure how to do it code as the error says the output shape should be "shape=(None, None, None, 1)" while in the prepare function I'm setting the shape to be "reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)", while IMG_SIZE = 50 as that was the resolution of the images I used to train the model.

Comment: Can you add in `print(X.shape[1:])` in your model?

Comment: After running it the output was: (50, 50, 1)

Comment: In your `prepare` function, just return `new_array` instead of reshaping it. Also do `print(new_array.shape)` before the return statement just to make sure the shape is consistent with `(50, 50, 1)`

Comment: After doing it printed out "(50, 50)" and I received an error stating: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 50)

Comment: just do `return new_array.reshape(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)`. Hopefully this should work?

Comment: I've attempted that before, it returns an error that it needs a 4 dimensional array. Actually I'll just put the error here: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 50, 1)

Comment: I found the solution, I just had to normalize the data just like I did when building the model. Basically I just added this "img_array = img_array/255.0" inside the the prepare function and now it works! Thank you for trying to help me Danny, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

In the model the data is normalized by being devided by 255.
I had to do the same thing to the array of new data inside the prepare function.

This is what the function looks like now and it works:

```
def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 50
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_array = img_array/255.0
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```